# How to ng-repeat childs in 'ng-repeated divs'?

Tags: html, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

**I want to create a list of items with subitems.** The items and the subitems are listed in arrays like this:

```
items=[firstItem,secondItem,thirdItem,...]
```

and

```
subitems=[{"name":"firstSubitem1","name":"secondSubitem1",...},{"name":"firstSubItem2","name":"secondSubItem2"},...]
```

So I've set up this html code:

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="" ng-init="items=[firstItem,secondItem,thirdItem,...],subitems=[{"name":"firstSubitem1","name":"secondSubitem1",...},{"name":"firstSubItem2","name":"secondSubItem2"},...]">
        <div ng-repeat="itemNames in items" id="item{{$index}}">{{itemNames}}</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

But that only outputs the list if *items*, and i want to make a list of items (*divs*) that have subitems (*paragraphs*). So the output that I want to create is this:

```
<body>
    <div (...) id="item0">
        firstItem
        <p>firstSubitem1</p>
        <p>secondSubitem1</p>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>

    <div (...) id="item1">
        secondItem
        <p>firstSubitem2</p>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>

    <div (...) id="item2">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

So how can I make it so that will be the output?

Comment: The objects in the array of `subitem` are not valid JavaScript. Objects are lists of `key: value` pairs.

Comment: @georgeawg thanks I'll change that in the question

Comment: there is no relationship shown for matching sub items to parent item for anyone to be able to answer this without more details. Take some time to read through [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restructure your data as following:

```
items = [{
    title: firstItem,
    subitems: [firstSubitem1, secondSubitem1, ...]
}, {
    title: secondItem,
    subitems: [firstSubitem2, secondSubitem2, ...]
}....]
```

And html to be as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" id="item.title{{$index}}">{{item.title}}
    <p ng-repeat="subitem in item.subitems">{{subitem}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: assumes that OP can restructure source. Can be mapped locally also

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on your data structure, use $index from the outer loop:

```
<body>
<div ng-app="" ng-init="items=[firstItem,secondItem,thirdItem,...],subitems=[{firstSubitem1,secondSubitem1,...},{firstSubItem2,secondSubItem2},...]">
    <div ng-repeat="itemNames in items" id="item{{$index}}">
        {{itemNames}}
         <p data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in subitems[$index]"> {{ value }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```